# Converting .XPT file into .CSV file

Tags: files

I have multiple files in the `.XPT` format. I want to convert all of them in the `.CSV` format. I am currently converting one file at the time by typing the following lines in Terminal.

```
R 

library('foreign') 

data=read.xport("~/Downloads/[filename].XPT") 

write.csv(data, file ="~/Downloads/[filename].csv")
```

Is there a way to convert multiple files with the same extension simultaneously?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a simpler way to do it in R, or as a shell script, but you can do it pretty easily perl.  Just insert this into a text file (name it foo.pl) and run it as "perl foo.pl"

```
my @files = sort glob("~/Downloads/*.XPT");
foreach my $file (@files)
   {
   ( my $csvfile = $file ) =~ s/\.XPT/\.csv/g;
   system "R;library('foreign');data=read.xport('~/Downloads/$file');write.csv(data, file ='~/Downloads/$csvfile')";
   }
```